# Changing the textwidth

Tags: indentation

Is it possible to change your text's width couple of times in one page? I would like to start the document with couple of lines that have been placed closer to the paper's edge and then return back to original textwidth after the headline. I have tried placing

```
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-0.75cm}
```

at the start of the document and after it "corrected" the width with

```
\addtolength{\hoffset}{0.75cm}
```

but the document counts these two together and every line starts at the document's original textwidth. This is what I have tried:

```
\begin{document}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-0.75cm}
This should be\\
closer to the edge\\
but it isn't\\
\addtolength{\hoffset}{0.75cm}
\begin{center}
Topic
\end{center}
And this should be at the document's original textwidth where it really is.
\end{document}
```

I tried to use `\setlength` but this time it only reacted to last command, which returns the width to original. Using \newenvironment might be the solution but I couldn't get it to work. I used

```
\newenvironment{headline}{\setlength{\hoffset}{-1cm}}{\setlength{\hoffset}{-1cm}}
```

with no success. Don't know if I did something wrong there or why it doesn't work.

I would be happy if someone could solve this problem or tell me that going back and forward with widths isn't possible in one page.

Comment: You can look on the site for `adjustwidth`; `\hoffset` is definitely not the right parameter to play with, because it acts on the whole page.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)